# how to display only the last four digits of an input field in angular material and angular js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I want to make an md-input field where only the last 4 digits will be displayed, like this,"********1234". I'm new to angular material and angular js, my knowledge is limited only to md-input password yet where all characters are hidden or replaced with "*". I made a javascript of this, and it worked! but i don't know what's the equivalent code of this in angular js. Here is my code: `$('#cardNum').bind('input', function () {
        $(this).val(($(this).val().replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, '*')));
    });

Comment: I made a javascript of this, and it worked! but i don't know what's the equivalent code of this in angular js. Here is my code: `$('#cardNum').bind('input', function () {
        $(this).val(($(this).val().replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, '*')));
    });`

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom filter for it:

```
appModule.filter('passwordMask', function() {
    return function (input, num) {
        if (isNaN(num) || num < 1) {
            return String(input).replace(/./g, '*');
        }
        var mask = RegExp('(.{1,' + num + '}$)|.', 'g');
        return String(input).replace(mask, function(hide, show) {
            return show || '*';
        });
    };
});
```

And use it this way:

```
<div ng-bind="passwordModel | passwordMask:4" class="password-style"></div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you explain the regex? How are you using the matching group with the `function (hide, show)` ?

Comment: @Guedes can i put it inside a controller?

Comment: @neaumusic. You can see the [regex in action here](https://regex101.com/r/pZ5iM3/1). The `hide` name was merely illustrative, since I didn't use it further. I used the `RegExp` just to concatenate the number of digits that can be visible (which will be matched in the group `show`), every other match/digit will return an asterisk.

Comment: @GlicerioRoble. You can use it right after the controller declaration: `module.controller('yourCtrl', function($scope){ /*...*/ }).filter('passwordMask', function(){ /*...*/ })`

Answer (score 1):

@Guedes can i use this in an input field?

```
<input  name="password" type="password" ng-bind="user.password | passwordMask:4" />

    myapp.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
      $scope.user = {
        name: '',
        password: '',
      };
    });
```

Comment: input need a ng-model... but ng-model doesn't allow a filter.

Comment: yes, but I need the input field to filter itself, any ideas?

Comment: you can try to mask using css, like this: http://jsbin.com/gakayupole/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: of course, you need to use also the filter. I didn't implement the filter on jsbin

Comment: In case of input field, the right solution is to create a directive. As the user will be able to type, it makes more sense to _filter_ when the element is created and in the event `onblur`. However, you might want to save the password value before changing it to asterisks